# Unknown pulses from SiPM without any source or detector?

Tags: experimental-physics, electronics, particle-detectors, noise, experimental-technology

I have a SiPM set up with its PCB, no amplification at all, reading out to an oscilloscope. If I supply 29.8 V, which is the maximum power (with overvoltage), I get some random peaks on the oscilloscope. I don't see these peaks below about 29.6V. There's no detector attached to the SiPM, there's no source, and the SiPM is in a light-tight box wrapped in aluminum foil. Where could these peaks be coming from, especially if there's no detector on the SiPM? What is happening within the SIPM to produce these pulses only near max. voltage?

Answer (score 1):

If

1. you are running very near breakdown voltage, and
2. the rate is very sensitive to the voltage that you are using

then you may be observing the extreme tail of thermal fluctuation triggering a cascade.

The other major suspect is cosmic muons because they get into everything, but I would naively expect that to be less voltage sensitive.

---

The datasheet for the device may be able to shed some light on exactly what to expect running the device near threshold, but that depends a but on the manufacturer.

---

How you deal with the spurious signals depends on the cause.

- To reduce thermal noise either reduce the operating voltage or cool the detector.
- To reduce contamination of your data by cosmic muons either bury the detector deep under ground or install an active veto.

Comment: Thank you! I too think it is either thermal or shot noise. yes, im trying to get rid of it by reducing the voltage without compromising my desired signals.